# How to upload to WebDAV using a web browser?

Tags: debian, webdav, upload

I've setup and configured webdav on debian using the following tutorial:

http://www.unix-tutorials.com/go.php?id=3711

I want to be able to download and upload files to the webdav share using a web browser. I can download and upload files to the webdav share if I mount it to my file system but we don't want the other people accessing this to have to do that. We want people to be able to go to the URL in their web browser, authenticate, and do everything, download, upload in their browser.

When I go to the webdav URL in my browser and authenticate I'm given a list of the webdav share's contents and I can download the files but I don't see any way to upload files? How can I upload files to the webdav share using a web browser?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61594705/1049542

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK there is no built-in support for webdav in browsers.

I think there are applications and AJAX libraries you could run on your web server that would make webdav through the browser possible.  A quick google search for [ajax webdav](http://www.google.com/search?q=ajax+webdav) showed one interesting looking product (http://www.webdavsystem.com/ajaxfilebrowser).  I have never used this, just happened to look neat when I did a search related to this question.

Comment: Looked cool and then... Holy crap! Single Server License: $ 1250 USD. Thanks for the heads up on the ajax webdav search. I hadn't tried that. I'll keep looking.

Comment: Ah, I didn't look at the pricing. :| That is unfortunate.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say which browser.  I thought it was built-in with Internet Explorer by simply using drag-and-drop.  I seem to recall a Firefox add-on.  I am looking for it now.

Edit:

> Webfolders is a firefox extension that gives you the ability to view the contents of WebDAV
>   servers in the browser and use the full functionality of the WebDAV protocol.

[webfolder add-on for Firefox](http://webfolder.mozdev.org/index.html)

Comment: It works for uploading files? You can upload files using webfolder and Firefox? I tried. I can't.

Comment: Sorry, it says full functionality.  I don't have a WebDAV server to test it with.